# Stop iAd call back methods

Tags: ios, admob, iad, banner

I've set up iAd in my iOS app. When I saw the fill rate, it is very low. So I would like to insert an AdMob(an other ad provider) banner when iAd banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError.

The process goes well but I do not find the way to stop iAd to call request. So if iAd bannerViewDidLoadAd, my app display both banners.

Is there any way to stop iAd request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the iAd delegate to nil and also set the iAd banner to nil. Setting the delegate to nil, you will not receive callback anymore.

Comment: When I do that, [banner setdelegate:nil],banner=nil; I still receive callBack methods. "[AppDeveloper] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does [...]". So it works but is it the proper way to do it ?

Comment: probably the banner is still owned by someone... remember to remove from its superview also, they objective is to deallocate it

Comment: You were right, my banner is handle in a singleton class but I had to set it to nil in my view controller too. I'm not sure to always understand the ARC mechanism ;). So, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to handle it would be to use a mediator like Admob to serve both kinds of ads. When your first option fails to deliver it handles the fallback to your 2nd and 3rd, 4th, 5th options.